# show (fade-slide) hidden text when you click on a main-text with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have tried this https://jsfiddle.net/e1b88ktf/
i want to apply a slide down effect when clicked on the main text.
and also the hidden text must go back when clicked again on the main text.

```js
function showText(show,hide)
{
    document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
    document.getElementById(hide).className = "hide";
}
```

```css
div.hide { 
display:none;}
div.show {
  
}
```

```html
<a onclick="showText('text1','text2')" href="javascript:void(0);">main-text</a>

<div id="text1" class="hide">
hidden text
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

thanks for all your help.

The text appears with a fade-in effect but the div with the background colour does not.
How can I make the background colour-div fade along with the text.

see updated **[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/826/)**

Comment: `$("#text1").slideToggle();` will work https://jsfiddle.net/e1b88ktf/3/

Comment: is there a way to make a fade down effect instead of slide ?

Comment: you will need to use `animate()` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @Vizz Check now this time it is fadeout and fadein instead of slide down and slide up

Comment: how to do in case of two texts https://jsfiddle.net/e1b88ktf/13/

Comment: How can I make the background colour-div fade along with the text. 
see updated question. http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/820/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution -

```js
function showText(text)
{
  $(text).animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 800); 
}
```

```css
div.hide { 
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <a onclick="showText('#text1')" href="javascript:void(0);">text</a>
<div id="text1" class="hide">
hidden text
</div>

<p><a onclick="showText('#text2')" href="javascript:void(0);">text2</a>
<div id="text2" class="hide">
hidden text 2
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to make a fade down effect instead of slide ?

Comment: @Vizz For that case use same class "hide" for all div's you want to hide on click of anchor, please check updated solution

Comment: @Vizz you can also pass the element you want to perform action check now I am passing element in function as argument.

Comment: How can I make the background colour-div fade along with the text. 
see updated question. http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/820/

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/822/  this is possible with your code as well only need to change the background color not on complete container but only on text area you are hiding

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jquery:

```
$("#text1").slideToggle().toggleClass("show hide");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamster/e1b88ktf/2/)

**EDIT**
and you don't have to add/remove classes to the div. The below will work too.

```
$("#text1").slideToggle();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamster/e1b88ktf/4/)

For fade effect use `.fadeToggle();`

Comment: is there a way to make a fade down effect instead of slide ?

Comment: @Vizz yes, use `.fadeToggle();`

Comment: how can I make the background colour-div fade along with the text. 
see updated question. http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/820/

Answer (score 0):

You can Do this using jQuery toggle() method.

**HTML** :

```
<div class="toggle">text</div>
<div id="text1">
  hidden text
</div>
```

**JS** :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").click(function(){
        $("#text1").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Here is working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/818/)**.

**UPDATE**

For multiple toggles, try below code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggle">
  text1
  <div class="hide">
    hidden text1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
  text2
  <div class="hide">
    hidden text2
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").click(function(){
       $(this).find(".hide").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Here is fiddle for multiple toggles: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/819/)**

Comment: This will work for multiple texts. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/819/).

Comment: how can I make the background colour-div fade along with the text. 
see updated question. http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/820/

Comment: Check this, background is fading along with text. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/821/)

Comment: how can i do it with the fadeToggle() and not with the scrolling one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML code:)

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <style>
   div.hide { display: none; }
   div.show { }
  </style>
  <script>
    function showText()
      {
       $('#text1').slideToggle();
      }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <a onclick="showText('text1','text2')" href="javascript:void(0);">text</a>
  <div id="text1" class="hide"> hidden text </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: How can I make the background colour-div fade along with the text. 
see updated question. http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/820/